# \nodexn and savedNodeCoors not playing nicely with each other

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

This question arose from trying to answer a different question previously posted by @StiffJokes (aka user:19356) but now deleted.

Each of the following MWE produces different results for the `pspicture` in a manner I find completely counter-intuitive.  The first two examples differ only in how the `border` for the `standalone` class has been set.  The third example uses the `article` class.

MWE #1:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
%% using pgffor just to see what happens at different values
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(3,3)
    \psset{saveNodeCoors=true}
    \pnode (0,0){A}
    \pnode (2,3){B}
    \foreach \myp in {0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.00}
    {
      \pgfmathparse{1-\myp}
      \edef\myq{\pgfmathresult}
      \nodexn{\myp(A)+\myq(B)}{V}
      \qdisk(V){2pt}
      \pnode(!  N-V.x N-V.y ){D}
      \psline(A)(D)
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in

[image]

MWE #2:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1in]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
%% using pgffor just to see what happens at different values
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(3,3)
    \psset{saveNodeCoors=true}
    \pnode (0,0){A}
    \pnode (2,3){B}
    \foreach \myp in {0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.00}
    {
      \pgfmathparse{1-\myp}
      \edef\myq{\pgfmathresult}
      \nodexn{\myp(A)+\myq(B)}{V}
      \qdisk(V){2pt}
      \pnode(!  N-V.x N-V.y ){D}
      \psline(A)(D)
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

resulting in:

[image]

MWE #3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
%% using pgffor just to see what happens at different values
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(3,3)
    \psset{saveNodeCoors=true}
    \pnode (0,0){A}
    \pnode (2,3){B}
    \foreach \myp in {0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.00}
    {
      \pgfmathparse{1-\myp}
      \edef\myq{\pgfmathresult}
      \nodexn{\myp(A)+\myq(B)}{V}
      \qdisk(V){2pt}
      \pnode(!  N-V.x N-V.y ){D}
      \psline(A)(D)
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

resulting in:

[image]

Can anyone explain what's going on here?  Why the differences?  On one level, the coordinates for `V` are correct since the points are being plotted where they belong.  But as soon as you try to use `! N-V.x N-V.y` to grab the coordinates for the center things go haywire.

By changing the coordinates fo points `A` and `B` the new coordinates for `D` can shift dramatically:

MWE #4

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
%% using pgffor just to see what happens at different values
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-1,-1)(3,3)
    \psset{saveNodeCoors=true}
    \pnode (0,0){A}
    \pnode (2,0){B}
    \foreach \myp in {0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.00}
    {
      \pgfmathparse{1-\myp}
      \edef\myq{\pgfmathresult}
      \nodexn{\myp(A)+\myq(B)}{V}
      \qdisk(V){2pt}
      \pnode(!  N-V.x N-V.y ){D}
      \psline(A)(D)
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `pgffor` is automatically loaded by default so no need to explicitly specify `\usepackage{pgffor}`.

Comment: @StiffJokes Never knew that.  Do you know why it's loaded by default?  Or better yet, where would I go to learn that `pgffor` is loaded by default?

Comment: PSTricks loads `pgfutil-common.tex`, `pgfkeys.code.tex`, `pgffor.code.tex`, and does `\let\pgfforeach\foreach`. It is "documented" in `pstricks.tex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\nodexn` uses internally helper nodes. And when nodes are set by nodes you'll get relative coordinates. Depending to the expression of `\nodexn` it works only with `\psGetNodeCenter{Node}`. A "simple" expression is like `\nodexn{1,1}{A}` (without the `()`), then the node values are the same.

And, by the way: writing such questions to the PSTricks mailing list makes more sense.

Comment: Where do I find the PSTricks mailing list?

Comment: So are you saying that the expression `N-<node_name>.x` etc is not supported in conjunction with `\nodexn`?

Comment: http://PSTricks.tug.org ...

Comment: it is supported, but depends to the expressions. Or in short words: do not use that notation when creating nodes with `\nodexn` And, of course, for nodes which are a linear combination of other nodes there are simpler macros ...

Comment: `(!N-C.x N-C.y)` is useful when using `\scale{-1 1}` because `(C)` and `(!\psGetNodeCenter{C} C.x C.y)` cannot be affected by `\scale`. `\nodexn` is also useful for creating complicated linear combination of some previously defined nodes. Thus `(!N-C.x N-C.y)` and `\nodexn` are both useful to use together, I think. :-)

Comment: Using `\nodexn{a,b}{<nodename>}` instead of `\pnode(a,b){<nodename>}` seems to be a rare case. In addition, the syntax `\nodexn{a,b}{<nodename>}` is also weird from linear combination point of view because `()` should be mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe by inspection that `\nodexn` does not respect the existence of `saveNodeCoors` so the variable `N-<node_name>.x` and `N-<node_name>.y` are left uninitialized.

The following code create 5 identical `pspicture` but `N-<node_name>.x`, and `N-<node_name>.y` produces different values each.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tools}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset{saveNodeCoors}


\begin{document}
\psLoop{5}{%
\begin{pspicture}(3,3)
    \pnode(1,1){A}
    \rput(0,2){\psPrintValue{N-A.x}}
    \rput(0,1){\psPrintValue{N-A.y}}
    %
    \nodexn{(1,1)}{B}
    \rput(2,2){\psPrintValue{N-B.x}}
    \rput(2,1){\psPrintValue{N-B.y}}
\end{pspicture}
\qquad}
\end{document}
```

[image]